# Get changes in a remote php in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

maybe this is a common question and I don't know how to pose it, but I can't find an answer for it.

I have a Project in Android Studio, which checks a remote JSON php that says if there's a notification to show to the user. If there is one, it creates a notification. The problem is that the application just does it ONCE, and if I make a loop it will consume a lot of MB of the user's internet contract.

I want to do something like Facebook does when you receive a private message.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use GCM, here you will find everything you need to start:
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start
Why GCM? you don't have to put a loop to check allways in the phone, you only have to send the notification to gcm, and gcm service that it's there will wake up your app, and you will get the message.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look